# How to Compile functions to C in parallel?

Tags: compile, ccompilerdriver

I need to `Compile` functions for use on parallel kernels. There are many such functions, so compiling in parallel is desirable. When compiling functions with `CompilationTarget -> "C"`, the compilation fails with multiple errors related to `CLangFormat`.

Is there a way to compile these functions without fancy formatting, so that - presumably - the compilation would succeed?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `` SymbolicC`Utilities`ClangFormatString `` is not designed for parallel
operation. It uses a hardcoded path that's same on all kernels. Thus, when invoked in parallel, it steps on its own toes.

This is true at least up to Mathematica 14.0.0.

A workaround is to disable fancy formatting on parallel kernels. The code is not for human consumption, so it is unnecessary anyway:

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  (* Parallel compilation fails if default code indentation is performed. *)
  (* SymbolicC`Utilities`ClangFormatString is not designed for parallel operation *)
  Needs["SymbolicC`"];
  SetOptions[SymbolicC`ToCCodeString, Indent -> None]
];
```